# 403 Forbidden on Apache (CentOS) Server as GUEST On Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, centos, virtualbox

These are my VM setup:

```
HOST: windows 7 ultimate 32bit
GUEST: CentOs 6.3 i386
Virtualization soft: Oracle virtualBox 4.1.22
Networking: NAT -> (PORT FORWARD: HOST:8080 => GUEST:80)
Shared Folder: centos
```

all the project files goes into shared folder and for each project file a virtualhost conf file is created in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` like `/etc/httpd/conf.d/$domain`

I wasn't able to see anything in my browser before disabling both windows firewall and iptables in centos after that if i type for example: `http://www.$domain:8080/` all i see is:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at www.$domain.com Port 8080
```

A sample Virtual Host conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #General
    DocumentRoot /media/sf_centos/path/to/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@$domain
    ServerName www.$domain
    ServerAlias $domain *.$domain

    #Logging
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/$domain-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/$domain-access.log combined

    #mod rewrite
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/$domain-rewrite.log
    RewriteLogLevel 0
</VirtualHost>
```

`centos` shared folder is availabe to guest at `/media/sf_centos`
These are file permissons for `sf_centos`:

```
drwxrwx--- root vboxsf
```

`vboxsf` group includes: `apache` and `root`

So these are my questions:

1- How to solve Forbidden Problem?

2- How to setup both host and guest firewalls?

3- How can improve this development environment to simulate production environment as much as possible specially security improvements?

Answer (score 0):

For #1/2: This is a permissions issue due to the auto-mounting method that VirtualBox uses. Instead of auto-mounting you have to mount it manually.

The post by suomynona (3rd reply) has some step-by-step instructions on resolving this issue:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=38891#p179152

As for #3, a standard practice is to have a staging server that mimics production as closely as possible (same OS, same updates, versions, etc). That will allow you to deploy from your local development environment for integration testing before you deploy to production. Sometimes we'll even set up our dev VM's to use the same OS as production for more complex projects where version/compatibility issues may cause headaches.